# Exception when calling replace_one in Python

Tags: python, pymongo

I'm trying to replace a document.

```
import pymongo

connection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")

db = connection.test
collection = db.foo

query = {}

try:
    cursor = collection.find(query)
except Exception as e:
    print "Exception: ", type(e), e

for doc in cursor:
    collection.replace_one({"_id", doc["_id"]}, {"foo", 1})
```

However, when I run this I get:

```
TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.Mapping
```

What's going here?  My method for `replace_one` looks the same as the one in the pymongo docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this comma between the items, you are passing in a *set*:

```
{"_id", doc["_id"]}
```

But should have passed a *dictionary*:

```
{"_id": doc["_id"]}
```

Same goes for the replacement document - `{"foo": 1}` instead of `{"foo", 1}`.

Comment: Thanks, only I've only just started Python.